# Monotony of $|a|^n(n^2+3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Is it true that $|a|^n(n^2+3)$ in case $a>1$ is increasing and in case $a<1$ is decreasing?

Comment: If you form the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle,$ where $b_n = (a_n)^n (n^2 + 3) ~:~ |a| > 1,$ then what is $$\left|~\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}~\right|?$$

Comment: It is |a| on the limit, right?

Comment: That is not what I am asking.  I am asking for the explicit expression in terms of $n$ for the fraction.  Also, consider the case of |a| < 1.$

Comment: $|a|\frac{n^2+2n+4}{n^2+3}$

Comment: Good.  Then [1] What can you say about this expression when $a > 1$.  [2] When $a < 1,$ it is trickier and you have to ask, under what circumstances will $n^2 + 3$ be greater than $|a| \times (n^2 + 2n + 4).$

Comment: If |a|>1 the term is >$(n^2+2n+4)/(n^2+3)$...but I am not understanding really

Comment: For question[1], what can you say about the comparison between $\frac{(n+1)^2 + 3}{n^2 +3}$ and $(1)$.  Can you say whether it is equal to $(1)$, $< (1)$, or $> (1)$?

Comment: What is (1)? Sorry can you be more clear?I am very confused!

Comment: I am in the process of writing an answer.  I held off until you showed work.  Now that you have shown work, mathSE protocol allows me to give a complete answer.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see the comments following the question, where the OP showed work.

Intended that $b_n = |a|^n (n^2 + 3).$

Suppose that $|a| > 1.$

Since $(n+1)^2 > n^2, \frac{(n+1)^2 + 3}{n^2 + 3} > 1.$

Therefore, when $|a| > 1,$ you have that $b_{n+1} > b_n.$

---

$|a| = 1$ can be considered trivial, since you know that $(n+1)^2$ is always greater than $n^2$.

---

Suppose that $|a| < 1$.

This is trickier.  In order to determine for what values of $n, \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ will be less than $1$, you have to consider when

$$(n^2 + 3) > |a| [(n+1)^2 + 3].$$

This translates into

$$\frac{n^2 + 3}{[(n+1)^2 + 3]} > |a|.\tag{1}$$

You know that $\lim_n\to\infty \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} = 1.$

Therefore, for all but a finite number of the leading elements of the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle$, the LHS of (1) above, which is strictly increasing and approaching $(1)$ from below, will be $> |a|$.  For those values of $n$, beyond the first finite number of elements of the sequence, you will have that $$1 > \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$.

This implies that for all but a finite number of leading terms in the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle,$ the sequence is decreasing.